# Does anyone have experience to use the confirmCredentials API in the AccountManager (Android)

Tags: android, accountmanager

I want to verify the userid and password is valid or not (such like Google account, Facebook account, Twitter account...).  I found and the **confirmCredentials** API in the AccountManager class. Could I use this API to verifty the password of the account?
   I write this **checkCredentials** API for checking user's password valid or not, but it will cause the ANR and I can't get the result of the password is valid or not?
   Do you have any experience about this API or how to verifty the id and password under Andoroid? 
   Any information or clue will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've used confirmCredentials in my app.  I've put some sample code below in case that helps...

```
public class MyActivity implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>

<snip>

    // Get the user to confirm their credentials 
    Account account = new Account("username", "com.mydomain.myapp");

    // The result of this call is handled in the
    // run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> response) method below
    AccountManager.get(this).confirmCredentials(account,
                                                null,
                                                this,
                                                this,
                                                null);

<snip>

  /**
   * Handle callbacks from the {@link AccountManager} methods
   */
  @Override
  public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> response)
  {
    try
    {
      // This call blocks while waiting for result from confirmCredentials
      Bundle result = response.getResult();

      // Handle the result
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
      // User cancelled login
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (AuthenticatorException e)
    {
      // Failed to login
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      // Always exit
      finish();
    }
  }
```